# Does this Kanji: 全効答 (Zen kō Kotae) mean "total efficiency" or at least convey it symbolically?

Tags: translation, meaning, pronunciation, sound-symbolism

I've been playing around with using Kanji as a quick way to convey a company's goals and/or ideals. As I understand it, **Zen 全** means *"whole/complete"*, **Kō 効** means *"efficiency/result"* and **Kotae 答え** means *"answer/solution"*. Does
**全効答** have a meaning of "total effectiveness" / "all right now" or does it simply become gibberish? Is the symbolism retained in the full statement of "Zen kō Kotae"? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're using 音読み for 全効, you may try also using 音読み for 答 which is とう. However, other than being a compounded term you may have coined yourself, it may not be understood by most people this way, if you read it as ぜんこうとう for example.

Comment: Imagine you didn't speak English and didn't know any of the rules for how words were put together, but you wanted to put a word together using some Latin roots and then stick an English word on the end, so you grabbed a dictionary and found some bits that look good, then you asked "Would *plefectanswer* mean 'total efficiency' to English speakers?"

Comment: Just to be the off-topic guy, it's 'kotae', not 'katae'.

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is "it is gibberish". It's not a Japanese word Japanese people recognize. It indeed looks like *plefectanswer*, as snailboat pointed out in the comment section. See also: [Can kanji compounds be formed arbitrarily?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17996/5010)

But each kanji is easy and has at least some positive meaning. So if you separate each kanji with a [nakaguro](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5851/5010) and write the phrase like:

> 全・効・答

...then it could be understood as the list of three concepts, like "Completeness, Effectiveness, and Answer". (I'm not saying it's a nice slogan, I'm only saying the meaning is at least understandable)

Comment: Also worth noting that these types of lists can eventually turn into something more like ‘words’ too if they become popular enough (like 報{ほう}・連{れん}・相{そう} ⇨ 報連相{ほうれんそう}). But that’s obviously a process which takes considerable time and adoption.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, 報連相【ほうれんそう】 is helped along by the existence of 菠薐草【ほうれんそう】.  (And, apparently, it's old enough that Microsoft has included 報連相 in the list of autocomplete candidates for ほうれんそう.)